# Convert Neo4j Query into asp.net query

Tags: asp.net, neo4j, cypher

I have a query which runs on Neo4j platform but I am trying to run that query from web page in asp.net but its not returning the result
any help.?
This is the query

```
match(p:Paper)-[:publish]->(j:Journal)
match(j:Journal)-[:held]->(y:Year)
where p.Name =~ ".*Relational.*"
return p.Name,p,y,y.Name;
```

This is my .net query

```
var temp = QueryManager.c.Cypher
          .Match("(auth:Author)-[writes]->(p:Paper)")
          .Match("(p:Paper)-[publish]->(j:Journal)")
          .Match("(j:Journal)-[held]->(y:Year)")
          .Where((Paper p) => p.Name == "~.*Relational.*")
          .Return((auth, p, j, y) => new
          {
              author_detail = auth.As<Author>(),

              paper_detail = p.As<Paper>(),

              jour_detail = j.As<Journal>(),

              year_detail = y.As<Year>()

          });
```